# create symlink in electron app

Tags: node.js, electron, symlink, fs

my app is based on drag and drop functionality so I can't start electron as admin to use fs.symlin() because d&g will get disabled when your app is running as admin on windows os
I'm trying to create symlink in ipcmain of electron

fs.linkSync(app.path,destination)

Answer (score 0):

so turns out d&d won't work in admin mode because of diffrences between two context, it is better to handle symlink creation in background, oh anyways i didn't reach any solution , there are some libraries like sudo-electron but when i want to create more than 1 symlink user will propmt like 10 times which is frustrating